# "Intra": can it be used just like "sub" or does it have extra nuance?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, grammaticality, differences, prefixes

I'm editing a draft academic paper at the moment that distinguishes between the variety that exists *between* several groups, on one hand, and the varieties that exist *within* one of those groups, on the other. The way the author has expressed this is by "inter-racial variety" and "intra-racial varieties", but there's something about this way of expressing it that rubs me up all wrong. Specifically, I think, it seems to me that "intra-racial varieties" should be "*sub-* racial varieties."

Here are some examples:

> "Kant advocates White intra-racial diversity." [looks fine]

> "[I]ntra-racial mixing leads to intraracial varieties” [looks odd to me; I
> would say subracial here]

Intuitively, "intra-" is used to refer to *connecting* objects with a group: e.g., intra-group dialogue, differences, or variety. I intuitively think that "intra-" is the wrong prefix to use to refer to objects that fall within a category.

A quick websearch suggests that I'm wrong by the definition, but all the examples I see arguably fit my usage: I see intrastate highways, intramural sports, etc., but not intragroups (subgroups is better) or intraspecies (subspecies is better).

Is my intuition right?

Comment: I think "inter" is also sub-optimal when refererring to things two groups do not have in common. Inter-group differences? meh. I also don't know what the phrase "variety *between* several groups" would mean.  Also, you're editing, not proofreading, when you question word choices.

Comment: Ah I'll have to increase my rates so!

Comment: Can you include a sentence or two where these terms are used?

Comment: sub-X is an X contained with in a larger X; sub-X would function as a noun if X is a noun. Intra-X would not be used with X being a noun, but as an adjective, specifically meaning within the X. Thus, intragroup doesn't make sense (but intragroup dynamics possibly could)

Comment: Are you sure these aren’t standard statistical terms related to the analysis of variance?  If they are, they have established meanings.

Comment: @SteveBennett, I have updated the post now.

Comment: @TimR, I've changed 'proofreading' to 'editing.'

Comment: @eques, I wonder if that's the answer!

Comment: @Xanne, could you elaborate? I don't quite follow.

Comment: Broadly, no. 'Intra' means 'within' and 'sub' means 'less than'

Does that much make sense?

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance.  Does the test use “variety” or “variance”.

Answer (score 10):

The prefix "intra-" means [within](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/intra), which works with your examples:

- intra-group dialogue: dialogue within a group
- intrastate highways: highways within a state
- intramural sports: sports within the walls

Your question is confusing, because first you talk about "the variety that exists between groups", then about "intra-racial *varieties*"; the word *variety* has different meanings based on whether it is used uncountably (eg "having different forms or shapes" [sense 1](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/variety)), or countably (eg "something different from others of the same general kind" [sense 3a](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/variety)).

If the paper talks about the sets of differences between groups and within groups, then "inter-racial" and "intra-racial" (respectively) would be a common way of distinguishing that; there's no need for a "connecting" aspect to the meaning.

If, on the other hand, it's referring to narrower *groupings* within a particular group, "intra-racial varieties" is probably confusing. But I'd be inclined to avoid "sub-racial varieties", because the prefix "sub-" can connote "inferior", which is not the message you want to be sending when discussing race.

Comment: "Intra-" works with those examples to be sure, but why is it confusing when referring to "narrower groupings within a particular group"? I'm glad you agree that it is confusing, though—that reassures me that my intuitions are reliable!

Good point re the connotations of "sub-", by the way—any suggestions for an alternative?

Comment: @JamesCamienMcGuiggan: I think to be more specific I'd need more details about how it's being used in the paper. I don't suppose it's publicly available (eg on arxiv)? Or can you clarify whether it's talking about "variety" or "varieties"?

Comment: I've added a few examples in the OP; re variety/varieties, the OP is sic. Is this helpful?

Answer (score 3):

I think your author is correct:

> **intraracial** *adjective*
>  Within, or occurring within, a race.
>  <sub>[selected attestation]</sub>
>  <sub>**1957**  
> These two groups [of early Man] are in effect intra~racial variants.
> —*Antiquity* vol. 31 196</sub>
>  <sub>Source: [*Oxford English
> Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

Variants within the race. Within-the-race variants. Intraracial variants. Intraracial varieties.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting up an inter/intra prefix distinction, I'd keep "intraracial" when needed (though it doesn't have to be used) and find standalone prepositions:

> There is variety *across* races with respect to ________, as well as variety *within* race.